# Labeling HTML table columns/rows with small cells

Tags: html, html-table

I'm working on an application that takes an image as input and renders the image within an HTML table (where the cells are analogous to pixels). When the table is rendered I'm also numbering every other column and row for a visual reference.

I've run into an issue where the size of the cell for "large" images is smaller than the text of the column/row labels, so what ends up happening is the size of the label text is throwing off the dimensions of the table.

<strike>You can see the application in action here: http://knit.ly</strike>
You can see a screenshot of what I'm talking about [here](http://lehmdogg.com/stackoverflow/knit_ly_screenshot.png)!

Ultimately I'd like to figure out a way to provide these visual column/row labels without affecting the size of the table cells. Another related question is it seems like I may be going down the wrong path with an HTML table but I'm not sure what other options I have. Maybe HTML 5 Canvas capabilities?

I'm curious to hear what solutions and/or alternative designs are out there.

Comment: Your application seems to be broken at the time of posting.(JavaScript errors)

Comment: I tried uploading what I thought was a large image to generate a pattern, but can't see any problems? Can you not resize the uploaded images to a standard width first?

Comment: Cool ap. Can you clarify what you mean? I loaded a big image into it but couldn't see what text you were talking about being larger than the containing cells. I could see only the measurements along the axes, and these fitted OK. As for whether or not to use a table, I'd say what you're doing here is actually a pretty good use-case for  table. Since this is all JS-generated (presumably), there's no semantics (i.e. SEO) question anyway.

Comment: The errors are on the main page. Did not (yet) test uploading files. For the app itself, tables are still the way to go for this(assuming people who knit do not all use modern browsers). You can try to get the labels to position itself absolutely within a relative table cell to avoid cell breaking.

Comment: My bad, this will only show up in the development version, not what is viewable publicly. I added a link to a screen shot in my original question. It's subtle but notice the difference between row heights between rows that are labeled and those that aren't.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. use a set width and `overflow:hidden` on the label cells;
2. [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) label cell text 90° (all modern browsers and IE9 support this in prefix form) and set `line-height` to the desired table cell width;
3. put a `nbsp;` with the same font and line-height settings in the blank cells.

Comment: According to the link you provided, it looks as though none of the major browsers support rotation properties. I verified Firefox does not honor it.

Comment: My stupid! Posted wrong link - should have been `transform`, which *is* supported. Corrected above, apologies.